# Column of type int not accepting Int value

Tags: sql, integer

I am facing an sql challenge here.
i have a database with a table called stockstable, & in this table, the only column with data type ***INT*** is ***quantity***.

Below is my code where i am trying to update values in the table but i get an sql error which says :
***java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'INTEGER' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'.***
But clearly i am writing an int in variable ***quantity*** into my table column ***quantity***.

The order of the table columns is exactly as is my SQL Query.
Where might i be going wrong?

```
public void updateItemData() throws SQLException{

try{
            Integer updatedQuantity = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldQuantity.getText());
            double updatedBuyingPrice = Double.parseDouble(jTextFieldBuyingPrice.getText());
            double updatedSellingPrice = Double.parseDouble(jTextFieldSellingPrice.getText());
            String updatedName = jTextFieldName.getText().toUpperCase();
            String updatedID = jTextFieldItemID.getText();
            String updatedDescription = jTextFieldDescription.getText().toUpperCase();
            java.sql.Date newReceivingDate = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooserReceivingDate.getDate().getTime());
            newReceivingDate.toString();
            
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Program Files\\ERS\\Database\\EmployeeDB", "axle","axle");
                        String list5 = "UPDATE STOCKSTABLE SET name = '"+updatedName+"',"
                        + "description = '"+updatedDescription+"',"
                        + "id = '"+updatedID+"',"
                        + "quantity = '"+updatedQuantity+"',"
                        + "systemdate = '"+systemDate+"',"
                        + "receivingdate = '"+newReceivingDate+"',"
                        + "buyingprice = '"+updatedBuyingPrice+"',"
                        + "sellingprice = '"+updatedSellingPrice+"' where id = '"+jTextFieldItemID.getText()+"'";
   
           
            ////////////////////////*********************************createStatement
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "QUANTITY :"+updatedQuantity);
            stmt.executeUpdate(list5);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HERE");

           //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(list5);
            ///////////////////////**********************************end of createStatement

     
         //jTableStocks.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
       refresh();
       jButton5.setText("ADD TO STOCK");
         
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update Successful");
               
                      
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update Error!");
            Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would be very vulnerable to SQL injection. I'd strongly recommend using a "prepared statement" or a parameterised stored procedure instead of simply building a query string by concatenation.

Comment: Thanks a lot...that solved my problem